# SDCard constantly being corrupted

Tags: usb, sd-card, filesystem-corruption

I posted this on stackexcange but people say it would be better to post here. So I copied and pasted

I have an sd card and I normally use it on a chromebook and it has no problems, but when I put it into my windows computer The SDcard will show 100% active time with a 0 response time and a 0 transfer rate. I then try to eject the card, but It will not eject, so I have to pull it out. Then I put the sd card back in and whenever I try to go to my sd card in File Explorer, it says "File or directory is corrupted or unreadable". WhenI go into the windows partition manager the sd card is being read as a raw partition. It will no longer work on my chromebook. I have successfully recovered all my data and done a full format (to NTFS) TWICE but it keeps breaking. How do I stop it from breaking? Is there a software or tool that I can use to completely wipe and error check the sd card. Also, Would formatting with a different File System work? I have no problems with any other sd cards or usb drives on my computer.

Comment: Have you tried using a different SD card adapter?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to use a different sd card adapter and I have used that adapter with other sd cards

Comment: You should check the file system. Chromebook is Linux-based AFAIK, so the default file system could be something like ext4, that Windows does not handle. Likewise, NTFS requires some tools like ntfs-3g to be read on Linux. FAT/FAT32 should work fine in both environments.

Comment: That would make sense. I will try a different file system. Also, chromebooks (For some reason) don't allow the ext4 filesystem even as read/write. The only weird thing is that the sd card works 100% fine in my chromebook, and only acts up on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern Windows systems will attempt to write their System Volume Information to the SD card when first inserted.  If you interrupt that process, the card may very well become corrupted.  The solution to that problem is to toggle the write lock switch on the SD card before insertion, preventing any data modification by Windows.

Comment: There is no write lock, it is a micro sd card, which is what modern computers use